# Creating random sample larger that range

Tags: python, random

I am trying to create a sample of 500 values between (and including) 60 and 126. ATM I've got:

```
random.sample(range(60,126),500)
```

but the syntax is invalid given the sample size is larger than my specified range.

Should I be using 'list' or some sort of iteration instead and if so, how?

Comment: you have range with ~60 values (it has only integer values) and you want result with 500 values  but `sample()` uses every value only once so it can create result only with ~60 values. You could need `choose()`

Comment: to format code you have to use ``` instead of `'''` - you get it with key below `ESC`

Comment: `choose()` @furas? Maybe you mean [`choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)?

Comment: @Mark you are right - I had not time to check in document correct name :)

Comment: For those who haven't read the documentation: `sample()` takes *without* replacement, while `choices()` takes *with* replacement. These are very different things. If you have `sample()` everywhere else in your code and these values actually matter for something, it might be good to double check which behavior you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
random.choices(range(60, 126), k=500)
```

This will return a list of 500 values where each value comes from the provided range. Values will be sampled from the same collection in each pick, so each value could appear more than once (even if the collection size is greater than `k`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.random.randint](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) for a faster and easier approach

```
np.random.randint(60, 127, size=500)
```